# Custom ASPxGridViewExporter

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I have an aspxgridview, I change displayed text via "CustomColumnDisplayText" event, My problem is when I want to use ASPxGridViewExporter for excel output, one of columns shows wrong data. I don't know how to use ASPxGridViewExporter RenderBrick event.

```
protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
{
if (e.Column.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString.Equals("Status"))
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt64(e.Value) == 2)
                    e.Value = "Successful";
                else if (e.GetFieldValue("SaleReferenceId") == null || e.GetFieldValue("SaleReferenceId").ToString() == string.Empty || e.GetFieldValue("SaleReferenceId").ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
                    e.Value = "Invalid";
                else if (e.GetFieldValue("saleOrderId") == null || e.GetFieldValue("saleOrderId").ToString() == string.Empty || e.GetFieldValue("saleOrderId").ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
                    e.Value = "Invalid";
                else
                    e.Value = "Unsuccessful";
                e.DisplayText = e.Value.ToString();

            }
}

protected void ASPxGridViewExporter1_RenderBrick(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.Export.ASPxGridViewExportRenderingEventArgs e)
    {
        // I don't know how to use it
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but this snippet works fine for me and the result is exactly what I wanted!

```
protected void ASPxGridViewExporter1_RenderBrick(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.Export.ASPxGridViewExportRenderingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridViewDataColumn dataColumn = e.Column as GridViewDataColumn;

            if (dataColumn.FieldName == "Status")
            {
                e.TextValue = "123";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```